# Why unripe, very young coconut fruits spoil in days, but the ones picked medium mature can keep months?

Tags: botany, fruit, decay

Coconut fruits can be collected at various stages of maturity.

Coconuts which are collected just when the flesh starts forming (about 5-6 months on-palm age), so they have very thin or almost no flesh, mostly just coconut water, they will spoil within just a few days in ambient temperature 30°C (86°F). Coconut water from such a fruit which stayed (in a n intact coconut) just a few days will start to taste off, and give stomach cramps.

As coconut mature on the palm, about 7-8 months of on-palm age, they grow more flesh and the flesh is becoming more firm, but not completely firm yet, while the outside of the coconut still remains more or less the same as the very young ones. Such coconuts will keep without spoiling much longer at the same temperature 30°C (86°F), provided the shell is intact, no cracks. Such coconuts are still considered young. I am not talking about fully mature coconuts, when the meat is completely hard and the outer shell starts to turn brown - this happens after about 10 months of on-palm age.

What biochemical difference is in the coconut water that prevent the medium-young (7-8 month) coconuts from spoiling as fast as the very young-picked ones?